# Loading and Unloading of modules in flex consume exponential memory

Tags: apache-flex, memory

Whenever I load a module using loadModule() function, memory usage increases.Its fine.\
But when I use unloadModule() function then also memory usage increases. I am also dereferencing the variables or objects. and also using removeAllChildren() function.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous sites with info about this - mostly they will tell you

1. flex uses a garbage collector model. your memory might have been deallocated but flex hasn't reclaimed the space yet.
2. use weak references for any eventlisteners.
3. make sure the module(s) are playing nice with memory also. your profiler should be able to tell you who is doing the larger allocations and how often.